# undefined method contact_path in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my routes defined as below

```
get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new'
```

And in my ContactsController I have defined as below

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
end
```

In views contacts/new/_form.html.erb I have structured form as below

```
<%= form_for @contact, html: {multipart:true} do |f|  %>

<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username %>

<% end %>
```

But when i go to **localhost:3000/contacts/new**

I get the below error.

**undefined method contacts_path** which is occuring in first line of form.

But when i try to define as below in routes, it worked

```
get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'contact'
```

Any idea why rails throws such error when i have defined it in the routes file. I am just trying to understand inner workings of  rails routes

Comment: back your controller to `get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new'` then type on console: `rake routes`.

Then change the route to `get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'contact'` and type again `rake routes`.

Compare the results

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this kind of errors, remove your route and use:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try better use railsy way like `resources` as @Graham mentioned.

or

```
get 'contacts', to: 'contacts#index', as: :contacts #genetares: contacts_path
get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new', as: :new_contact #new_contact_path
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make a post type route for contacts (for this it is throwing error)**

Or remove this route

```
 get 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#new'
```

And add this simply

```
resources :contacts
```